# How Can I Run My Search Box Without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I want to remove JavaScript. But it does not work without JavaScript. What is the solution for this, please any modified code?

Comment: You can't add interactivity only using CSS. Also, if you want people to understand your code, please don't post it obfuscated.

Comment: CSS can detect `hovers`, `before`, `after` and `checked` to apply styling but not functionality. It's impossible to properly make your website function without JS.

Comment: I update My Post Please See Again

Comment: Why **exactly** is it not working? Tons of other pages work pretty good without having JS enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS means casacade style sheets, how do you want to create forms and functions with it? You definitely need js.

In other words, css is for the visuals, javascript to give it functionality. You just can't create methods using css.

Comment: Please See My Post Again

Answer (score 2):

CSS is used to style the content and JS is the proper way to handle clicks and go some logic. Explain what you mean by damaging the system and I will try to help you fix it.

Comment: Actually I am Blogspot Blogger. JavaScript is slowing down the site. So I want to code without JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry but JS doesnt (generally) slow down the website, if your website is slow it is likely due to the content, can you be more detailed in what JS is slowing down and also post the code

Comment: But Sir Any Method To Make Onclick Event From CSS?

Comment: No that is simply not possible. As i said CSS is used to style the web page (i.e. colours, layout etc.) not detect on click

Answer (score 1):

CSS is for styling only (colours, font style etc.) as mentioned by others. Adding 'interactivity' by css would be somthing like this

```
.search-button a:active{background-color:#000;}
```

Change style on active or hover etc, but thats about it.
Personally I wouldn't say this is interactive. Javascript shouldn't slow down your website as its used by thousands of websites extensively eveyday. If it is then you need to take a look at the javascript code and debug it.

Regards

Comment: Please See My Post Again I am Update This Post